# Problem with reusing ViewPropertyAnimator objects

Tags: android, android-animation

Using the straightforward `View`'s `animate()` works very well, however when I assign the returned `ViewPropertyAnimator` to a variable and attempt to invoke `start()` on it, doesn't seem to work at all.

What I tried and works:

```
view.animate()
        .alpha(0)
        .setDuration(400)
        .start();
```

What I tried and doesn't work:

```
public CustomViewConstructor() {
    ViewPropertyAnimator animation = view.animate()
            .alpha(0)
            .setDuration(400);

    // problem #1: Starts immediately here

    ViewPropertyAnimator animation2 = view.animate()
            .alpha(0.5)
            .setDuration(100);
}

customViewCallback() {
    animation.start();

    // problem #2: animation2 will be cached and used instead
}
```

---

### EDIT:

I made sure the callback is called, which means that `start()` is indeed invoked, but I see no result at all.

I have a reason to resort to such separation because I want to cancel the animation at other times. Any other ways to cancel animations by reference would be appreciated also.

---

### EDIT:

I used two different animations for the same view in its constructor, swapped hide animation and show animation places, where show animation is declared last, and got different output. The view is stuck at the last frame of the show animation which means previously it was stuck at the last frame of the hide animation also. This still shows that `start()` is not starting the animation!

---

### EDIT:

According to documentation, turns out that `start()` is only used when we want to immediately, synchronously start the animation instead of leaving it start when ready, so declaring the animations in the constructor means both of them start at the same time.

So far, the problems I'm facing with this approach are:

1. The ViewPropertyAnimator stored in variables is always the last one built using `animate()`, sort of a 'cache' built-in.
2. The animation actually starts right away, needless of `start()`!
3. Can't really find a way to temporarily pause the animation until I manually invoke `start()`.

Comment: I have tested this. It works for me. Where do you call animation.start(). Please post more code about it.

Comment: @aminography updated with a more similar case

Comment: So what is your reason about creating animation in constructor then start it later? Is it possible to you to create and start animation at the same time?